# Interchanging calculus operations with pi product

Tags: calculus

In the domain of convergence, we can interchange derivatives, sums and integrals but what about $ \prod$ and previous operations?

For example,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j(x) =  \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{d}{dx}f_j(x)$$

and,

$$ \frac{d}{d u^i} \int_{a}^{b} F(u_1,u_2,u_3..) du_j = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{d}{du^i}  F(u_1,u_2,u_3..) du_j $$

for $ i \neq j$

But, how would I interchange product and derivative like:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \prod_{i=1}^{i=n} f_i(x)=?$$

One indirect way I did was this:

$$ g(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{i=n} f_i(x)$$

Take log of both sides and then,

$$ g'(x) = g(x) \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \frac{ f_i^{'}(x) }{ f_i (x)}$$

Would there be more direct interchanges as I had shown before/ alternate proofs of this identity?

Comment: Your second assertion, about interchanging derivatives and integrals, needs a few hypotheses. Your last assertion seems to be missing a "prime" on the left-hand side. But when that's included, what you've written is probably about as good as it gets --- the product rule for derivatives is more complex than the sum rule.

Comment: But in your last equation, right-hand side,  $f'(x_i)$ should be $f_i'(x)$ in the numerator, and there should be no subscript $i$ on the $x$ in the denominator. (And you still need to add the prime on the left-hand side.)

Comment: fixed all of them, thank you ^^

Comment: The way I was brought up to do the product was to take logs and then differentiate, getting $\frac{g'}{g}=\sum_i \frac{f_i^{'}}{f_i}$.

Comment: That's what OP did in the last formula, but I admit, I like the symmetry of your version a little better.

Comment: I changed the index of summation in several formulas: you had $j$ as a index, and then kept writing $f_i$, so I just changed the index to $i$.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the derivative of a product gives you
$$\frac{d}{dx} \prod_{j=1}^{n} f_i(x)=  \sum_{j=1}^n f'_j(x)\prod_{i=1 \\ i\neq j}^{n} f_i(x).$$

Comment: ...which is exactly the same as OP's last equation, except for minor typographical errors. OPs formula has the advantage of involving only a single "big" operator, but the disadvantage of not "cancelling" one factlor in the product $g(x)$ in the individual terms of the sum.

Comment: @JohnHughes: possibly the nicest way to write the formula is to write $\frac{g'}{g}=$.